# как сделать примерно такую верстку чтобы когда выбираешь из выпадающего списка товар и тут же указать его количество?

Tags: javascript, html, css

товаров может быть много
поэтому селект должен быть multiple

тоесть выбрать несколько товаров и при выборе товара указывать его количество

может это сделать без стандартного селект

Comment: Взрыв мозга просто, а можно как-то реалистичнее сделать? Насколько я понимаю вы хотите сделать что-то типо добавление товаров в корзину, если да, то там в корзине можно выбрать его количество.

Comment: @Проста Miha типа корзины, но это будет выбиратся в админке а не на сайте как привычно добавил товар в козину а потом там поменял количество но похоже придетяс делать типа выбираешь в списке товар и появляется строка как в корзине и там уже указать количество

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли я всё понял или нет, но вот что я сделал.
Надеюсь хотя-бы немного помог.

```js
var expanded = false;
const checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
const inputsChk = checkboxes.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
const inputsNum = checkboxes.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]");

function showCheckboxes() {
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.children.length; i++){
  inputsChk[i].onclick = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.children.length; i++){
      if(inputsChk[i].checked) inputsNum[i].classList.add("show");
      else inputsNum[i].classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 225px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}

input[type="number"]{
  display: none;
}

input.show{
  display: block;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
      <select>
        <option>Выберите продукт</option>
      </select>
      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <label for="one"><div><input type="checkbox" id="one" />Продукт 1</div><input type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1"></label>
      <label for="two"><div><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Продукт 2</div><input type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1"></label>
      <label for="three"><div><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Продукт 3</div><input type="number" min="1" max="99" step="1"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```